# Coerenza ontologica di 'non vedo una mazza'

Tags: word-usage, idioms, phrase-origin

Come noto la 'mazza' è un cilindro sottile e molto allungato, così nessuno dovrebbe meravigliarsi, o quasi, di non vedere una 'mazza' trovandosela davanti. Cionondimeno spesso sento dire 'non vedo una mazza' quando, in condizioni di oscurità o semioscurità, o comunque di difficoltà visiva, uno non riesce a vedere qualcosa.

Allora mi chiedo, non dovrebbe dirsi 'non vedo un elefante', per dire che è così difficile vedere, quale che sia la ragione, che se anche ci fosse un elefante non lo si vedrebbe.

Epperò si dice 'non vedo una mazza'.

Sapreste dire perché viene usato il termine 'mazza' e qual è l'origine di questa espressione?

Comment: I believe the misunderstanding is that you assume a club, a "mazza", is thin while it is usually thought as a rather stout, thick object (it is a weapon, after all). This is also the reason why it is used as synonym for male genitalia.

Comment: @Kyriakos: Mazza, aside from the genital reference, is best translated with 'bat' or 'mallet'.
The item you refer to is called 'stecca' or 'spranga'.

Answer (score 21):

I am afraid the ontological meaning of "mazza" is … [male genitalia](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mazza_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/). And the original expression is "non vedo un cazzo" where "cazzo" is a rude synonym for male genitalia. Meaning and usage are mentioned in the [Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cazzo/), nº2.

Comment: Yes, I think it's the right answer. _Non vedo un cazzo_ means _non vedo niente_, and since _mazza_ is also used as synonym of _cazzo_, also _non vedo una mazza_ means _non vedo niente_.

Comment: @randomatlabuser, why are you censoring the word “cazzo”? This is a site about Italian words, structure and language, and while the terms we *use* in our explanations are expected to be on the polite side, the words we *mention* are just as they happen to be, aren't they? There was a discussion about this in Meta, some time ago (http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/16/how-to-handle-swear-words), and the consensus was that, when in the right context, there is nothing wrong about mentioning swear words and the like.

Comment: @DaG OK, I have uncensored the term :-) Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: I agree this is the right answer, but I think it comes from "minchia", not from "cazzo".
The "polite" way to say "non vedo un cazzo" is "non vendo un cacchio o cappero".

Comment: While I think that most if not all native speakers would agree with you, I must say that this cannot be the whole truth, since a sentence like _ma che mazza fai?_ is, as far as I know, NOT possible (this also shows that @Bruno9779 is probably wrong). It looks like _mazza_ can only appear in negative sentences with the indefinite article (_non ... una mazza_).

Comment: @WalterTross However you could say *ma che cavolo fai?*, which can also be used as *non vedo un cavolo*. It seems like the word *cazzo* has many "polite" alternatives and not all of them sound very well in all sentences.

Comment: @Bakuriu, I don't quite understand your comment. I believe that you can replace _cazzo_ with _cavolo_ in **all** sentences containing the former (in the sense number 2 in the [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cazzo/)), while this is not true for _mazza_

Comment: @WalterTross I'm saying that the above answer *is* the whole truth. The fact that we don't say *ma che mazza fai?* doesn't imply anything a part from the fact that certain combinations of words sound better than others, which is a trivial fact.

Comment: In my first comment I should have said "this cannot be the whole story", instead of "the whole truth". I don't believe that this answer is wrong, only that it's incomplete (it got my +1 nonetheless)

Comment: @Bakuriu, I disagree. It's not a matter of "sound". The point is that _cazzo_ and _mazza_ (in the sense discussed) belong to different classes of words. The former is interchangeable with _cavolo_ and _minchia_, the latter with _tubo_ and _piffero_, except that _piffero_ has the additional usage _"... del piffero"_. And then there is _accidente_. Set-theoretically speaking, if S(_w_) is the set of sentences that can be formed with word _w_ (in the sense discussed!), S(_mazza_)≡S(_tubo_)⊂S(_piffero_)⊂S(_accidente_)⊂S(_cazzo_)≡S(_cavolo_)≡S(_minchia_). Sound alone cannot explain this.

Answer (score 1):

L'argomento è semplicissimo: trattasi qua di espressione volgare, lungi da aver a che fare con la falegnameria o altre arti e mestieri.

"Mazza" è sinonimo di "..azz", "minchia", "tubo", "cavolo", "accidente", e chi più ne ha, ne metta

Answer (score 0):

L'espressione "non capisci una mazza" è tipica messinese. Si riferisce al generale Francesco Mazza, mandato a Messina subito dopo il terremoto da Fracesco Crispi nel 1908. A quanto pare il Mazza non fece niente per aiutare i terremotati e invece rimase a bordo della nave soccorritrice non sapendo cosa fare, anzi complicando ancor più la vita ai superstiti. Dopo un mese fu rimandato a Roma. Era impreparato. Non capiva niente... Non capiva una... mazza!!!!

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Hai qualche fonte per questa interpretazione?

Answer (score -1):

#### Utilizzo della parola

L'espressione che hai citato è più o meno utilizzata dipendentemente dalla provenienza della persona che scrive o dice, essa non è un'espressione volgare come alcuni altri hanno espresso, è un'espressione più forte di "non ci vedo nulla" e meno forte di "non ci vedo un cazzo", quest'ultima con l'utilizzo del vocabolo cazzo è considerata volgare in quanto contiene un vocabolo di tale definizione. È necessario comunque notare il significato di [volgare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/volgare1/). Mi permetto inoltre di dissentire con coloro che affermano che mazza stia per pene, questo dipende da regione a regione ed è dialettale. Mi permetto di dissentire anche con coloro che dicono che essa sia un'espressione volgare e che qualunque madrelingua sarebbe d'accordo.

#### Significato ed utilizzo

Il significato è che la persona dicente questa frase non riesce a vedere nulla. Questo può essere dato da carenza di luce o di oggetti che impediscono la vista al soggetto, analogamente può essere pronunciata quando si è illuminati in viso dal sole e viene complesso osservare i dintorni perché abbagliati dai raggi solari. L'espressione è analoga ai [phrasal verbs](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/phrasal-verbs) inglesi *se proprio vogliamo fare un paragone* (cosa che preferirei non fare ma può essere utile), essa non ha senso grammaticalmente, l'unico senso è quello datole dal lettore. Prendiamo l'esempio del phrasal verb inglese "fill out" con il significato di riempire un questionario o form, il suo significato grammaticale è riempire fuori. Questo è quello che si verifica con l'espressione italiana "non vedo una mazza". Vi sono molte espressioni che variano di utilizzo da regione a regione, io uso spesso "non ti svegli nemmeno con colpi di cannone", il significato è semplice ma mai ho provato a sparare con un cannone.

#### Errori di interpretazione

Hai detto che la [mazza](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mazza/) è un oggetto cilindrico, sottile e molto allungato. La tua affermazione è ahimé sbagliata, la mazza come da definizione ed uso comune è un'arma preistorica utilizzata per i combattimenti definita come robusta e generalmente corta, cosa che va contro la tua affermazione.

#### Etimologia

L'etimologia di questa espressione è a me sconosciuta ed è anche difficile da trovare online, preferisco non effettuare supposizioni per non cadere in tragici errori.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Benvenuto/a! Dovresti sostituire i tuoi "cui" con "che".

Comment: @vincenzo-oliva Non devo sostituire alcun "cui" con "che", esso può essere usato come forma obliqua di "che" con significato "il quale", "la quale" etc. Ammetto che nel primo caso l'articolo lo scuona male. [Treccani cui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cui/) [Corriere cui](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/C/cui.shtml)

Comment: @M.Petri Benvenuto/a! Come dici giustamente, è la forma *obliqua* di *che*, e in quanto tale non può essere usata come pronome relativo nei complementi *diretti*. Per cui frasi come *la persona cui scrive* significa *la persona alla quale scrive* e non *la persona che scrive*, che immagino sia il significato da te inteso. D'altronde è vero che il valore di complemento diretto esiste (è citato nel dizionario del Corriere come "letterario"), ma non lo raccomanderei nei casi in cui esso può essere ambiguo

Comment: Come anticipato da Denis, si può utilizzare solo **per i complementi indiretti**, oggi almeno. Cito la pagina Treccani che hai linkato: "con un’unica forma per ambedue i generi e numeri: _il progetto di cui ti ho parlato; la questione a cui accennavi; nelle condizioni in cui siamo; il luogo da cui venite; l’aereo con cui parto; i motivi per cui son venuto_. Inoltre si può usare senza preposizione solo quando è complemento di termine (viene omesso _a_) o con valore aggettivale di specificazione (compreso tra un articolo e un sostantivo).

Comment: Provvedo a cambiarlo per evitare ambiguità.

Answer (score -2):

Ho letto la risposta di @randomatlabuser, ma non credo sia così.

Infatti, come noto, la 'mazza', anche storicamente, è l'oggetto più semplice da realzzare nei lavori di falegnameria. Ed è forse questa la ragione per cui si dice 'non ho fatto una mazza' per dire, per esmpio, di non aver fatto nulla, neanche una minima cosa (alias, la mazza), rispetto ad un impegno programmato.

Allora, ciò stante, l'espressione 'non vedo una mazza' è una evoluzione, nell'ambito del vedere piuttosto che del fare, dell'espressione 'non ho fatto una mazza'.

Dubito fortemente che nelle suddette espressioni ci siano allusioni agli organi genitali maschili, comunque.

Quindi, sotto l'aspetto ontologico, 'non vedo una mazza' è un'espressione incoerente, atteso che la mazza è un oggetto che, in senso relativo, si vede piuttosto difficilmente.

Comment: È una risposta alla tua domanda o una controrisposta?

Comment: _Mazza_ is a synonym of _cazzo_, even when used in _non vedo una mazza_, which is another way of saying _non vedo un cazzo_ (= _non vedo niente_; "I don't see anything").

Comment: @egreg, certamente non una *controrisposta*, semmai un ulteriore contributo; ma noto che *kiam* è piuttosto deciso sulla questione, anche se mi sembra stia interevenendo *a gamba tesa*.

Comment: Un contributo che, pur senza votare a sfavore, ritengo poco costruttivo. Che una mazza sia semplice da realizzare è una tua idea e dubito che i falegnami sarebbero d'accordo.

Comment: Ciò che taglia la testa al toro è questa semplice domanda: _Non vedo una mazza_ è un'espressione volgare? Qualunque madrelingua ti confermerà che lo è, e questo dimostra che non si sta parlando di mazze in senso letterale.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis There is no reason to suspect that the meaning of *mazza* is not *cazzo*. Swearing is common in spoken Italian, and even present in Middle Ages literature (*Taide e` la puttana*, *del cul fatto trombetta*, ...). The process of substituting a swear word for a(n often) similar sounding, acceptable one, is called euphemism (Non capisci un cazzo -> un cavolo, Cristo -> cribbio, porco Dio -> zio, ...)